# Boolean logic in config.txt conditional filters

Tags: config.txt

When using conditional filters in config.txt, is it possible to use boolean logic for specific GPIO combinations?

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
[gpio24=0,gpio25=0,gpio26=0,gpio27=0]
do_this_thing=1
[all]

[gpio24=0 & gpio25=0 & gpio26=0 & gpio27=0]
do_this_thing=1
[all]

[gpio24=0 && gpio25=0 && gpio26=0 && gpio27=0]
do_this_thing=1
[all]

[gpio24=0][gpio25=0][gpio26=0][gpio27=0]
do_this_thing=1
[all]
```

Raspberry Pi config.txt conditional filters: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md

Comment: You really need to address this question to the authors of the software. As a general point if a feature is not mentioned in the documentation you shouldn't use it. Even if it happens to work it might be removed without notice.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi Foundation engineers have noted in the past that the documentation may not always be up to date or the best and that better answers are on the forums. I have posted this question on their forums as well and if I get a response I'll update this posting.

Comment: You could always try the method in the documentation i.e. each condition on a seperate line.

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#combining-conditional-filters) is a little vague on this, it says:

> Filters of different types can be combined
> simply by listing them one after the other

But it also says:

> Filters of the same type replace each other

This means `[gpioNN=X]` conditional filters are actually treated individually, and each condition ends when the next is encountered. For example:

```
[gpio26=0]
# this block is processed when GPIO 26 is low.

[gpio26=1]
# this block is processed when GPIO 26 is high.

[gpio25=0]
# this block is processed when GPIO 25 is low
# regardless of the state of GPIO 26. 

[all]
# this block is always processed
```

As far as I can tell the only way to do an "AND" condition with GPIO filters is to split your /boot/config.txt over multiple files, and switch to a different config with the `use` keyword, which will cause a branch in the execution. For example:

```
# in config.txt:
[gpio26=0]
use config2.txt

# in config2.txt: 
[gpio25=0]
# This block will only be processed if *both* 
# GPIO 26 AND 25 are low.
```

It is important to note that you have to use the `[all]` stanza to resume normal processing; a simple line-break won't do.